# Scanned image filtration

Tags: document-scanning

I scan documents into images, but my table (where I scan the documents) forms the border of images.

So the images I get ain't the pure document I want to obtain.

Any suggestion? Something like filter software will be big help, thanks

Comment: Close the top of your scanner.?.

Comment: I use portable scanner, so I scan it by moving the scanner through the document and I don't know how to prevent scanning the table

Comment: You probably can't. You'll have to clip the pic after scanning.

Comment: Have a look at this post: http://superuser.com/questions/613670/auto-crop-black-margins-dynamically-of-scanned-images